# How to tell a dropdown to always expand to the top

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a p-dropdown in the footer of a p-table. Those are PrimeNg Components. I noticed the dropdown sometimes opens to the top, which I like in this particular case and I'd like to force it to always open to the top.

In the Doc's of p-dropdown I couln't find anything useful. I there maybe a CSS-Option which does me help here? Please advice.

`<p-dropdown [options]="myTypeOptions" [formControlName]="type" appendTo="body" [showClear]="true"></p-dropdown>`

Answer (score 2):

I see that, when the user clicks on the combo box, the p-dropdown component creates a div with the class `ui-dropdown-panel` (among others) to show the scrollable list of options. Depending on the position of the component it will be show either below or over it (by default, it's below) to avoid overflowing. By default, when the dropdown div is displayed over the combo, its position is set implicitly using the following CSS styles:

```
top: -202px;
left: 0px;
```

So, perhaps you could force the `top` property to be always -202px with some CSS:

1 Apply an special class to the component to display the list over it:

```
<p-dropdown styleClass="showAbove" [options]="myTypeOptions" [formControlName]="type" appendTo="body" [showClear]="true"></p-dropdown>
```

2 In the component's CSS file, set the default position for the dropdown div:

```
.ui-dropdown.showAbove .ui-dropdown-panel {
  top: -202px !important;
}
```

**EDIT:**
This doesn't work, the component substracts 202px to the -202px we've set in the above CSS, so it displays the panel 404px above. Another approach could be handling the `onClick` event and use Angular `Renderer2` to change the div `top` value. I'll do some tests when I have a minute and I'll post an update.

**PROPOSED SOLUTION:**
Sorry for the delay, I don't have much spare time lately... To show you a working solution, I've done a little Stackblitz app so you can play with it:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-2nwkvt

Feel free to ask whatever problem or doubt you have.

Cheers!

Comment: I really like to see that Renderer2 example, did you manage do create one?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css to p-dropdown:

```
bottom: 100%;
```

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work (dropdown.d.ts.Dropdown.html:1 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'bottom: 100%')